# Why Rect .env gives Production if Node is set to staging?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, environment-variables

Why React frontend gives me env === production, but pm2 clearly is set to "staging". My react app is set to be built with "build:staging". I found this from rect off. website:

[image: screenshot]

What is the point to make a staging build if your frontend still gives you
"process.env.NODE_ENV === production"? Am i doing something wrong?

Left Screen from browser, right from pm2:
[image]

Comment: It's hard to say what might be wrong without seeing your build step and build scripts.

Comment: `"build:staging": "env-cmd .env.staging npm run build",
`

Comment: "[...]You can specify other environments[...]" (React off. website) - Why, if they will not work. I do understand that really, my .env.staging was integrated into the code, but why then should i integrate it if the front-end is still in production? I see no logical explanation why it should be so "by design".